# What's meaning of the phrase "to be required"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What's meaning of the phrase "to be required" and why it is? I saw some translate it to active voice and I felt so confused. For example, the sentence

> They don't seem to be required at all.

is translated into

> They don't need something at all.

Comment: 'require' becomes 'be required' in passive voice.  They require warm clothes - active voice.  Warm clothes are required by them is passive voice.

Comment: "That they don't seem to be required at all" is not a sentence. Please, can you give the whole original sentence?

Comment: the sentence is they don't seem to be required at all.Maybe I have some grammatical mistake.I feel so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by the OP the sentence at issue is

> They don't seem to be required at all.

Let us assume for concreteness that the *They* refers to replies

> Replies don't seem to be required at all.

So the speaker originally thought that is would be necessary to reply but has now been told that it is not necessary or has worked that out in some way. It would be possible to replace *required* here with *needed* with the same meaning.

Comment: I think the noun means someone or something specific,if follows your assumption,we would replace that sentence with replies don't need something rather than replies are not be needed.